# DFS for finding if route exists between two nodes

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I am trying my hand at implementing DFS but having some trouble on this.

First, I managed to get a simple DFS example working which just prints out the nodes as it visits them.

```
def DFS_helper(self, node, visited):
    if node == None:
        return

    print(node.val)
    visited.append(node)

    for child in self.getChildren(node):
        if child not in visited:
            self.DFS_helper(child, visited)


def DFS(self, node):
    visited = []
    return self.DFS_helper(node, visited)
```

Notice that in the above code example, I do `self.DFS_helper...` instead of having that be a `return` statement.  Why is this?

Now, I am trying to determine if two nodes in a graph are reachable.  Here is my attempt.

```
def _isReachable(self, nodeA, nodeB, visited, stack):
    if len(stack) == 0:
        return False

    if nodeA == nodeB:
        return True

    front = stack.pop(0)
    visited.add(front) # mark the node as visited

    for neighbor in nodeA.neighbors:
        if neighbor not in visited: # if it's not already been visited
            stack.append(neighbor)
            return self._isReachable(neighbor, nodeB, visited, stack)

# given a directed graph, returns true if there is a route from nodeA to nodeB
# Returns false otherwise
# this method essentially runs a DFS from nodeA to nodeB
def isReachable(self, nodeA, nodeB):
    if nodeA == None or nodeB == None:
        return False
    if nodeA == nodeB:
        return True

    stack = [nodeA]
    visited = set()
    return self._isReachable(nodeA, nodeB, visited, stack)
```

Not only does it not work, I'm not quite sure I understand the difference between calling a recursive function and returning the results of it.  I have tried both ways without avail.  Any help on the code and conceptually for me would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe `DFS_helper(self, node, visited), DFS(self, node), _isReachable(self, nodeA, nodeB, visited, stack), isReachable(self, nodeA, nodeB)` are class methods. If not then there is no point in calling them using `self.fun()` syntax. `return self.DFS_helper(node, visited)` is perfectly alright.  Recursion is happening inside `DFS_HELPER`

Comment: Can you get us the sample output and input? What is nodeA? a class? list? sist of list? a element in dict? there is not enough info.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your return statement:

```
return self._isReachable(neighbor, nodeB, visited, stack)
```

In here, you break off after finding the result of the first child, instead of aggregating results of all children.

Look at this example:

```
source: a
target: d

      a
    /   \
  /       \
 b          c
            |
            |
            d
```

Now, if you traverse the graph via `(a,b)` before `(c,d)`, this return statement will mean you are not going to explore `c` and then `d`, and you will answer `d` is not connected.

To solve it, you need to return `_isReachable(b,...) or _isReachable(c,...)`

(And of course, generalize it for more than two children per node)